# Django 1.5 Mysql 5.5(InnoDb) transaction not rollback in exception

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, innodb

I am using django 1.5 Mysql 5.5(InnoDb) on ubuntu 14.04. I am creating multiple objects in the create method,

```
    @transaction.commit_on_success
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       try:
         v1 = Voc()
         v1.save()
         v2 = create_guest(v1)
      except Exception:
         logger.exception('Exception')
```

If there is any exception in create_guest method, it should rollback the v1 object as well, this behavior is observed when both Djnago and MySql are on the same machine, however if the database is on another machine, the rollback of v1 object doesn't happen. I have tried everything like commit_manually and savepoints, however nothing is working.
Any help or insight will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code so that it will be easier to understand for people.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @transaction.commit_manually 
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        v1 = Voc()
        v1.save()
        v2 = create_guest(v1)
        transaction.commit()
  except Exception:
     logger.exception('Exception')                               
     transaction.rollback()
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to describe your answer a little bit, as opposed to just posting the code; not to say this is not a good answer, it might be exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: I have even tried this, however it didn't worked for me. I am not sure if this is some environment issue, or I am missing some very basic point.